# Key and Required data annotations

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-annotations

When using the entity framework there are the following data annotations:

- [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.KeyAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Just for reference, I using the definitions from [this wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key):

> Primary Key
>
> 1. A primary key cannot allow null values. (You cannot define a primary key on columns that allow nulls.)
> 2. Each table can have at most one primary key.
>
> Unique Key
>
> 1. A unique key can allow null values. (You can define a unique key on columns that allow nulls.)
> 2. Each table can have multiple unique keys.

Is the `KeyAttribute` used to denote a primary key or is it used to denote a unique key?

When using annotations would the following be considered reduntant or necessary?

```
class Example
{
    [Required(), Key()]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, that would be redundant as your models require a key value to uniquely identify them once they have been annotated with `Key`.

And as an aside, if you are using Code-First, even `Key` would be redundant as by convention a property called `Id` or `ModelNameId` would be used for your primary key.

Comment: Is there a place where these are better defined?  The MSDN articles on both say nothing about what they do.

Comment: Re: `Key`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.keyattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx "Specifies one or more entity properties to use as the unique identity for the entity." You can have unique fields that don't necessarily identify an entity. A field that stores hashes of passwords springs to mind.

Comment: Right, but nothing in there says that a Key must be required, only that it must be unique.

Comment: Keys are not required on the entity, but if a property is decorated with the `Key` annotation, a value for that key is required. I'm not sure if I've ever read that, I just draw the conclusion from how primary keys function.